# gsub() only working after copying vector back from output of dput()

Tags: r, web-scraping, vector, gsub

I have the following problem: I scraped prices from multiple webpages.As for some webpages the price is scraped as `html_text()`, it contains things as currency or ".-" after the price.

Now if I try to remove these things from the price itself using `gsub()`, it doesn't fully work.
Also if I then try to convert the prices to integer using `as.integer()`, it gives me just NA's for every price.

The strange thing is that if I use `dput()`to get the content of the vector shown in the console and then copy this content and save it as a new vector (like `vec<-c("5.-","10.-","9.-")` it suddenly works and I can properly use `gsub()` and `as.integer()`.
Does anyone know why this could be happening?

The code I use to scrape the prices is:

```
input_galaxus2<-paste0('https://www.galaxus.ch/',input_galaxus$`Galaxus Artikel`)

sess <- session(input_galaxus2[1])             #to start the session
for (j in input_galaxus2){
  sess <- sess %>% session_jump_to(j)         #jump to URL
  
  i=i+1
  try(vec_galaxus[i] <- read_html(sess) %>%   #can read direct from sess
        html_nodes('.sc-algx62-1.cwhzPP') %>%
        html_text())
  Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=1, max=2))
}
```

and the `j` inside the code refers to the product number that can be pasted just after the base url, for example 14513912, 14513929 or 8606656

Edit: so the product links are for example: https://www.galaxus.ch/14513912, https://www.galaxus.ch/14513929 and https://www.galaxus.ch/8606656

Comment: We need a full example URL to create an answer e.g. `https://www.galaxus.ch/some_article.html` not just the base domain

Comment: Ok, I update the Question so there are some full examples of product links. Basically, you can just copy the example product numbers after the base link and this will get you to the product URL

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rvest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     guess_encoding

"https://www.galaxus.ch/8606656" %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('.sc-algx62-1.cwhzPP') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  str_extract("[0-9]+") %>%
  as.integer()
#> [1] 385
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Use `as.numeric` and `[0-9.,]` to get the cents, too.

Comment: Thank you very much, it did work!

Do you know by any chance why `as.integer` seems not to work with another scrape code that i'm trying?:
`vec_tectake[i] <- try(paste0('https://www.tectake.ch/de/',j)%>%
                          read_html %>%
                          html_nodes('.price') %>%
                          html_text() %>%
                          str_extract("[0-9]+") %>%
                          as.integer())  
}`

`j` is e.g. "2-aerobic-hanteln-800383", so the link would be "https://www.tectake.ch/de/2-aerobic-hanteln-800383"

Comment: The website https://www.galaxus.ch/8606656 does not have a html tag of class `.price` but only `.sc-algx62-1.cwhzPP`

Comment: This code is about a new website "https://www.tectake.ch", but I managed to make it work somehow. Thanks very much for your help!